# difference between post and get requests

Tags: postgresql, post, python-requests, get, fastapi

Why should I use a `post` request instead of `get` when I add some info in my database like `PostgreSQL`. I can just put all necessary data in arguments with `get` request, like this:

```
@app.get('/get_offer_and_return/{id}/{name}/{age}')
def get_offer_and_return(id: int, name: str, age: int):
    #some code where I am adding all this data to my postgresql db
```

and then just use `requests.get` where I'll put in the data.

Why that is worse than `post` request?

Please answer where is the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946325/why-should-i-post-data-rather-than-get

Comment: In addition to the links above, I would also suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) (specifically, take a look at Solution 1, paragraph 2) about the risks of passing sensitive data in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The guidelines typically follow:

> Use GET for safe andidempotent requests.

> Use POST for neither safe nor idempotent requests.

Take a read here: [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

This can answer more elegantly than I.